# Swift/iOS: How to implement horizontal collapsed?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a new one of iOS developing. Now I need to implement below function: the two pictures are two status of a `UIViewController` which is presented by `UIPresentViewController()`. When click ">", the 2nd one will be shown, when click "<", the 1st one will be shown. How can I implement it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: would you paste your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack views to achieve this.

You will need two stackviews for this. One for the icons and second for name of icons both with vertical axis laying out parallel to each other.

sV1                              sV2

————           ———————

| icon 1 |    | name of icon 1 |

| icon 2 |   | name of icon 2 |

| icon 3 |   | name of icon 3 |

————           ————————

```
sV2.isHidden = false
```

Now when you click expand you can make the second stackview’s hidden property to false and when you click collapse you can make that hidden.

```
sV2.isHidden = true
```

If you want animation, you can wrap the layout if needed in uiview animation block after you set the hidden property.

```
UIView.animate(timeInterval) {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**Edit**:

These stackviews should be contained in a new parent stackview.

Now you can add constraits to the parent stackview to stick to the left of its super view which is root view of your viewcontroller.

If you want to fix the width of icons stackview you can add width constraits independently to ensure that left stackview doesn’t get misplaces when other stackview is hidden.

So the new hierarchy will be like this

UIViewController —> View —> Parent Stackview —> sV1 | sV2.

Parent Stackview is fixed to left anchor to left anchor of View and right anchor is fixed to right anchor of View with greaterThen equality. So when sV2 is hidden sV1 remains in its position.

Comment: since the UIViewController is presented by UIPresentViewController, the  width of UIViewController cannot be changed after it is presented. How to make sure the most left uiview width isn't change but the UIView includes icon and name of icon can move smoothly when sV2 is hidden and shown?

Comment: When sV2 is hidden, I want the width of ParentStackView fit to sV1. When sV2 is shown, the width is sV1+sV2.